# Automatically add help page in empty ASP.NET WebApi project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've created an empty ASP.NET Web API project and I've been working on it for some time. At the beginning I wasn't thinking that I would eventually need a help page and APIs description. Is there any way to add this page automatically in an empty ASP.NET Web API project or will I have to create a new project or find some other work around?

I want to have this page with my APIs.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add the [Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Help Page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage/5.2.3) Nuget Package to your project and the help pages will be automatically generated.

For more info see: [Creating Help Pages for ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages)